# Clone Azure Dashboard and adjust ApplicationInsights tiles

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have 3 separate Azure subscriptions that have identical and each subscription is paired to an environment e.g. dev, uat, prod.  Under each sub/env I have identical Application Insight instances for each application that I deploy.  Within each Application Insight instance I construct several dashboard widgets/charts/analytics and pin them to my custom published dashboard.  Currently for each instance I have to recreate each widget/chart/analytic and pin them to a dashboard.  Is there any way to clone a dashboard or widget to point to another Application Insight instance?  I tried using the Azure Resource API but did not get solid results.

Answer (score 7):

In order to clone dashboard tiles and edit the analytics queries from one dashboard to another, do the following:

1. Download the first dashboard json.
2. Open the json, search for ResourceId property. 
   Replace the ResourceId to the desired ResouceId application which you'd like to monitor.

   You can get the ResourceId of an application from the Overview blade:
   For example for this application:
   [image of my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYnNE.png) you can get it from the url: subscriptions/7948c75a-ee6e-4c34-b391-52ba5dca56dd/resourceGroups/raz_group/providers/microsoft.insights/components/raz_test1      be sure to clear the /overview in the end.
   After replacing the ResourceId, delete the SubscriptionId, ResourceGroup and Name properties near it. You don't need those.
3. Go to the second dashboard (or create a new one) and upload the new json.

Please tell me if something isn't clear,
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Azure Dashboards can be deployed using Azure Resource Manager templates. Here is a document that details the operation.

[Programmatically create Azure Dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-nepeters)

Comment: Can you do the same for shared analytic queries?